# WPA2 enterprise: username/password-prompt-less setup on a mixed network: XP/SP3, Mac OS X, Linux, iOS

Tags: certificate, freeradius, wpa2

I asked a question recently about [setting up WPA2 enterprise](https://serverfault.com/questions/410495/how-many-user-supplicant-certificates-are-needed-for-wpa2-enterprise-for-the-hom), and I have a couple of ancillary questions. First, regarding the use of the OpenSSL cnf files for the certificate generation. I have a number of them in `/etc/raddb/certs`, which came in part of my freeradius installation on my Gentoo box. I have a `ca.cnf`; `server.cnf` and `client.cnf`. My questions are as below:

1. If i want to set up username/password-prompt-less setup for WPA2 enterprise (I want the users file to use certificates)--can I do this following the same procedure I followed for "The windows XP client" in Step 1 of [freeradius howto](http://wiki.freeradius.org/WPA-HOWTO)? I will add the eap.conf configuration as mentioned in the answer to my question above. Note that this is an issue I am facing in Mac OS X based systems. My windows XP/SP3 laptop does not seem to have this issue, as I added the ca.der file (double-click install), and the client.p12 file to it (see [freeradius howto](http://wiki.freeradius.org/WPA-HOWTO), under Step 1, "The windows XP client").
2. How do I import the specific keys onto iPhones and other personal devices such as iPads, Android tablets etc.?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but something to think about in such a setup: Why allow **personal** devices on a network? Did you give you full rights to encrypt the devices or delete all data on all of those devices if they ever got lost? If not then BYOD is a really  bad idea from an admin/security point of view.

Comment: @Hennes: this is for a home network. However, the "personal" in the personal devices really means phones, ipads which typically support only one user (no username/account/password business on an iPhone). Note that you could have a corporate mobile device that needs to get onto WPA2 enterprise securely. Eg. corporate iPhones and iPads. I use such devices regularly in my line of work.

Comment: Aye. I know places which use them. E.g nurses with an ipad and a custom application. However I also know several corporate places where all desktops and laptop got tied down with full HDD encryption, but all data was allowed onto BYOD machines without any security. I guess that still itches.

Comment: I run full disk encryption on all my home computers. Doesn't everybody?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Heh heh ... :-) Comment appreciated. This is part work-based project, part paranoia, but I have family members whose WiFi has gotten hacked (resulting in bad things thereafter), and I know they appreciate it when I tell them I have military grade security on the home WiFi network. The part of about WiFi security is not about home security (inside the home, you can trust), but prevention of your (global) IP address being used by random strangers, not to mention hogging bandwidth. Now, none of this is security enough for a determined hacker. I'll give you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much poking around man pages for `openssl.cnf` and the configurations on the various iPhones and iPods at home, I have finally figured out the answer to the question I posed.

My solution achieves the following: (a) username/password-less logins in a secure manner using EAP-TLS via WPA2-enterprise, and (b) (maybe a teeny bit stronger security) password-less but username required login in a secure manner via WPA2-enterprise. The option (b) is really by uncommenting `check_cert_cn` in the `eap.conf` file, and requiring the username (there are a number of `name` attributes, be a little careful) is sent. A potential hacker could have your certificate, but she possibly does not have your username, but this is not exactly a security measure for a hacker who knows her way around certificates and WPA2 enterprise.

In a gist, the procedure is that you will change the `client.cnf` file for each client you want to add into the network and regenerate the keys using `make client.pem`, which produces the `client.p12` file which you should download onto your client machines--this means each client gets its own key for the encryption, which implies one client in the network cannot spy on another's packets via promiscuous mode. If you have any issues during the creation of the `client.pem`s: `make client.pem` bombs for any reason, then pay special attention to `serial` and `serial.old`, and `index.txt` and `index.txt.old`: specifically, `mv serial.old serial` and `mv index.txt.old index.txt`, and redo the `make client.pem` after the problem is fixed (e.g., incorrect `cnf` file due to typos--most likely due to the fact that special characters are sometimes not permitted for the passwords in the `client.cnf` file--I would appreciate anyone reading this to point me to resources regarding the use of special characters in `*.cnf` files).

Now the details: Windows machines need a different procedure: For each Windows XP client, you will need to use the techniques mentioned in the `README` file in `/etc/raddb/certs/`. Next, you should follow the steps in "Step 1: Create Certificates: On the Windows XP client" in the FreeRadius [howto](http://wiki.freeradius.org/WPA-HOWTO), and [connect using Step 4 of the same howto in the FreeRadius site](http://wiki.freeradius.org/WPA-HOWTO).

For all machines, before you do the above for each client, you should change the `client.cnf` file for usernames and passwords for each of the clients. My `cnf` files changed really only touched the `[ req ]` section of the `client.cnf` file to change `distinguished_name`, `input_password` `and output_password`. Note that the following section should describe the name of the client described as the value for the `distinguished_name` attribute. For example, if you had `distinguished_name = beeblebrox` in the `[ req ]` section, then the following section will start as [`beeblebrox ]`. Here, you will configure the attributes accordingly boringly (same for most clients in your network, except the `emailAddress`, which will change for each client).

At the end of this process, you are done generating the `*.p12` digital profiles/personal information exchange file for each client. This file contains a private key which the client will use for communication in the network. Now you have to install these digital profiles on to the clients.

Windows machines will take the procedure for installation of the certificates and the connection to the WPA2 enterprise network as already mentioned above. All the other machines need the `*.p12` file that was created for them (it is convenient to name them per client: `xp1.p12`, `xp2.p12`, `ios1.p12`, `ios2.p12`, `macosx1.p12` etc.) to connect to the RADIUS server. How do you download the `*.p12` file onto the machines **securely**? For laptops, the problem is trivially solved by the use of removable media or if you are connected via ethernet to the host network, an scp of the file. For iPhones and other devices, it is a tiny bit tricky. I am not sure if using insecure email is the way to go, considering the fact the `*.p12` file [contains the private key](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4/cxf_security/i298613.html) to be used by the clients. Perhaps you digitally encrypt your email so it is OK. But I solved it by hosting the `*.p12` files locally on a webserver and downloading them onto the IOS devices.

On the MAC, you can follow the steps provided in [here](http://www.engin.umich.edu/caen/network/wireless/old/mac.html) but make sure you add the `*.p12` file to the keychain on your MAC before you do so (see [here](https://www.racf.bnl.gov/docs/howto/grid/osxcertmgmt)). The 802.1x authentication in your WPA2 enterprise configurations (you may have to explicitly check `TLS` in the configuration).

On the IOS devices, you first download the `*.p12` file which will let you add this certificate as a profile (download of the `*.p12` file starts the process automatically). Then, you go to settings->WiFi->add your WPA2 enterprise network, and specify the SSID, and then change the mode to `EAP-TLS`. Once you do that, the `Identity` option appears, which, when you click, offers the `*.p12` profile option. Check the option, and return to the screen. Depending on whether or not you have chosen total username/password-less login to the enterprise system, or password-less login, you may have to enter the username from the corresponding `client.cnf` file used to generate the `*.p12` file. Once you click join, you are in!

I'd appreciate someone adding the plug for wireless access via linux.

I'll pipe in once I can talk more on the number of times I have to re-login etc.--I might have seen this problem on my IOS devices, but I have to check again.

Comment: a client connected to a WPA2 protected wireless network can not sniff the non-broadcast packets of another user, even if there is a shared key. a per-client key is derived when the client associates to the AP. therefore, clients can not decrypt the packets of other clients.